# Why can I not access files on another computer on my network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, permissions, file-sharing, workgroup

I have set up the workgroup all to the same word, for this I'll replace it with SUPERUSER. When I try to access files from another computer which is also on SUPERUSER, a pop up comes up and says:

> Windows cannot access \PC\d-drive\USER\IMAGES
>
> You do not have permission to access \PC\d-drive\USER\IMAGES. Contact your network administrator to request access.

Both computers are on Windows 7 x64.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: keep in mind, if all the computers belong to the same workgroup ... it still does not give access to any folders or files. You still need to share them and allow access to them. Workgroups allow a group of computers to be combined or separated from one another (like a VLAN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sharing issue, you can just create an admin account, give your name and password of it, and add the account to the permission list.

If you do not would like to do this (as you choose the option "password protect off"), you can modify this group policy:

Computer Configuration-> Windows Settings ->Security Settings ->Local Policies ->Security Options, find this:

Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts

http://blog.hansmelis.be/2009/09/06/administrative-shares-in-windows-7/

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/

Comment: ok, thx, I edit it ))) It is the thoughts of Big Brother).

Comment: I glad. See my answer at Virtual Box and MacOS. Good luck!

Comment: Your Virtual Box Tutorial worked. Thanks so much, you've been really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 computers using Windows 10 Home version and on the newest computer to the network.  The other two computers were showing but I could not access them.  After spending 5 days looking for a solution on the Internet to no avail, I decided to try something new.
I quit my HomeGroup on all 3 computers and then made a new HomeGroup on the newest computer.  Proceeded to connect the other 2 computers to the new HomeGroup and Walla, could connect to all the other computers plus the printers that are being shared.

Hope this help someone as it sure did make me happy